# Create a Table in SQLite with the following fields

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have this method to create SQLite database, now am wondering code command that will create a table in the database called `Medical_Information` with column `id` as `AUTOINCREMENT, INT`,and then `Time` of data type `DateTime`,`Dosage_description(VARCHAR255)`.

```
//Method to create database in slite
    public void createDatabase(){
       SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Dosage", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    
    }
//Method to create table
```

Comment: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-create-table/

Comment: What have you tried? Was there an error? Please update the question with some code samples of the you used and what went wrong.

Comment: Am confused with how to list the columns for the table fields like in my question, can you suggest somethig?

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for creating table is:

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (columnName1 valueType1, columnName2 valuType2...);
```

Below syntax will create table like as you wanted.

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE Medical_Information (" +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "Time DATETIME, " +
                "Dosage_description VARCHAR(255))";
```

You can also use [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl) for creating database and tables and you can use that database or you can create database and tables and you can copy syntax for creating table from SQLiteStudio.

**EDIT:**

> Can you post for inserting sample data into table?

Either you can use SQL syntax or insert() method.
Syntax for inserting data into table:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (column1, column2....) VALUES (value1, value2,...);
```

Using `ContentValues` with `insert()` method:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(columnName, value);
db.insert(tableName, columnHack, values);
```

Inserting data with SQL syntax:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Medical_Information (Time, Dosage_description) VALUES (datetime(), 'test')";
db.execSQL(sql);
db.close();
```

Note: `datetime()` is a time function of SQL so you can't use it with `ContentValues` (but you can use Java's time methods). Inserting data with `insert()` method:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("Time", sdf.format(new Date()));
values.put("Dosage_description", "test");

db.insert("Medical_Information", null, values);
db.close();
```

Comment: Can you post for inserting sample data into table?